# careers.stackoverflow.com can't find my answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Trying to fill out my profile at careers.stackoverflow.com but I am unable to **"Link to 5 Stack Exchange answers"** as requested.

> Sorry but the Stack Exchange Network is having trouble finding your answers. Please try again later.

```
"NetworkError: 404 NotFound - https://careers.stackoverflow.com/stack/answers/314396?_=1447346729229"
```

Is something broken here or am I missing something in the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they've just made a typo in the link, `/stack` should be replaced with `/cv/stack`.

The correct link is:

https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/stack/answers/314396?_=1447346729229

As [the script](https://cdn-careers.sstatic.net/careers/Js/stackanswers.js) is having trouble with the link, it hides the answer chooser, which you were going to [manually make appear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269278):

```
t ? ($(".answers").text(Careers._s("Sorry but the Stack Exchange Network is having trouble finding your answers. Please try again later.")), $(".open-chooser").hide()) : .....
```

So if the link is replaced with the working one, the answer chooser will appear.

Comment: nice catch - guess it'll be fixed shortly

Answer (score 5):

Yup, there was a path bug introduced as part of the on-going work on [integrating the job board](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310066/stack-overflow-serving-programmers-even-better) into Stack Overflow. I've fixed it up and pushed to production.

Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1):

Using the web inspector I was able to find a hidden `<div>` with the class `answer-chooser` near the **Top Answers** section.  Unchecking the style rule `display: none` reveals a section which is indeed capable of selecting different sites and retrieving my answers.  Sadly, upon page refresh my added answers still don't appear - though they are now missing from my available selections so I guess they are saved somewhere and will someday be visible.

Assuming this is a bug but maybe it's a challenge test to see how savvy you are at hacking the stack exchange careers forms.

Comment: They didn't want you to hack - provided an explanation in my answer :)